# Process.StartInfo of Process.GetCurrentProcess() throws InvalidOperationException in .NET 6 unit test

Tags: c#, process, resharper, system.diagnostics

I have a .NET C# project that compiles against different target frameworks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net461;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
        ...
```

A unit test in VS 2022 (done via Resharper Unit Test sessions) accessing StartInfo of the current process is working fine with 4.6.1, but fails with an exception with net.6.0.

```
 using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
         {
            Assert.IsTrue(process.StartInfo != null);
         }
```

Exception text:

```
*Test method HSBC.Diagnostics.Test.ProcessProxyTest.TestProcessProxy threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: Process was not started by this object, so requested information cannot be determined.
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StartInfo()
    ...
```

What is the reason for it?

I see that for both platforms, the used mainmodule is ...JetBrains\Installations\ReSharperPlatformVs17_95e6680d\TestRunner\net461\ReSharperTestRunner.exe.

Update: this happens also with a quite simple console application:

// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
using (Process process = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
{
   if (process.StartInfo != null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Process.StartInfo found.");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, seems like it was never valid to access StartInfo like that from processes that have not been returned by Start()...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo?view=net-6.0

You should only access the StartInfo property on a Process object returned by the Start method. For example, you should not access the StartInfo property on a Process object returned by GetProcesses. **Otherwise, on .NET Core the StartInfo property will throw an InvalidOperationException and on .NET Framework it will return a dummy ProcessStartInfo object**.